# General question about Binary files

Tags: python, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am a beginner and I am having trouble in grasping binary files. When I write to a file in binary mode (in python), I just write normal text. There is nothing binary about it. I know every file on my computer is a binary file but I am having trouble distinguishing between files written in binary mode by me and files like audio, video etc files that show up as gibberish if I open them in a text editor.

How are files that show up as gibberish created? Can you please give an example of a small file that is created like this, preferably in python?

I have a feeling I am asking a really stupid question but I just had to ask it. Googling around didn't help me.

Comment: Every file on your computer is not binary.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: Do you mean "Not every file on your computer is binary"?

Comment: @John yes, that is another way of saying what I mean. What I said is somewhat ambiguous, I'll admit :(

Comment: Every file on your computer *is* binary.  Some of them happen to contain encoded text.

Comment: @Rafe: Wrong. "every X is not Y" != "not every X is Y". What you said is NOT ambiguous.

Comment: Its a good question and framed in a very direct and intelligent manner. I am sure everyone starting out programming thinks about this. I know I did. And I'm sure this will be asked again, though probably not as clearly probably. So marking this one so that I can simply link to the answers here. +1.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a literal answer to your question:

```
import struct
with open('gibberish.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(struct.pack('<4d', 3.14159, 42.0, 123.456, 987.654))
```

That's packing those 4 floating point numbers into a binary format (little-endian [IEEE 756](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) 64-bit floating point).

Here's (some of) what you need to know:

Reading and writing a file in binary mode incurs no transformation on the data that you read or write. In text mode, as well as any decoding/encoding to/from Unicode, the data that you read or write is transformed according to the platform conventions for "text files".

Unix/Linux/Mac OS X: no change

older Mac: line separator is `\r`, changed to/from Python standard `\n`

Windows: line separator is `\r\n`, changed to/from `\n`. Also (little known fact), Ctrl-Z aka `\x1a` is interpreted as end-of-file, a convention inherited from `CP/M` which recorded file sizes as the number of 128-byte sectors used.

Comment: I ran that code and yes that did show up as "gibberish" but I am still confused. What did that code do? I looked up struct module in python doc but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. It did answer my question but I still feel unsatisfied. But thats not your fault. Someone linked to me the [BMP image file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). By the looks of it even a "simple" format looks complex to me. But if I were to code this format by hand I would just write bytes according to that format to create the file like you did?

Answer (score 4):

> When I write to a file in binary mode (in python), I just write normal text.

You'll have to change your approach when you upgrade to Python 3.x:

```
>>> f = open(filename, 'wb')
>>> f.write("Hello, world!\n")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be bytes or buffer, not str
>>> f.write(b"Hello, world!\n")
14
```

But your question isn't really about binary files.  It's about `str`.

In Python 2.x, `str` is a **byte** sequence that has an overloaded meaning:

- A non-Unicode string, or
- Raw binary data (like pixels in an image).

If you print the latter as it were the former, you get gibberish.

[Python 3.x](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html) got rid of this double meaning by introducing a separate `bytes` type for binary data, leaving `str` unambiguously as a text string (and making it Unicode).

Comment: If I were to write Raw binary data like pixels in an image, how would I do it? I am not talking about using PIL or imaging library but writing binary data in general like you said.

Comment: You store it in a `str` (2.x) or `bytes` (3.x) object.  You can use `\x` escapes to represent the non-printable characters, e.g., `yellow = '\xFF\xFF\x00'`.

Answer (score 3):

So-called "text" files are simply files that follow certain conventions: the bytes are usually a subset of all the possible bytes, generally ASCII or Unicode values, and are organized into "lines" with "line terminators". The standard line terminators vary by platform - Unix uses `\n`, Mac `\r`, and Windows `\r\n` - so part of the convention is to translate these on the fly. This works fine with text files, but will clobber other kinds of files, because an `0x0a` (`\n`) byte in a sound file or something won't take well to being converted to `0x0d` `0x0a` (`\r\n`). Of course, if you've only been using Unix, this won't have come up.

In Python 3, all strings are Unicode, and opening a file as text means you have to read and write Unicode strings, and perhaps specify an encoding (it defaults to UTF-8). Opening a file as binary means you have to use `bytes` objects, which are simple lists of 8-bit bytes and don't get encoded.

Does this clarify things?

Comment: Mac OS X uses Unix line endings (`'\n'`).  It's only old Mac OS versions (up until version 8 or 9, I think) that used `'\r'` for line endings.

Comment: I should have thought of that - of course it would, it's Unix now. THanks.

Answer (score 2):

Binary files are normally created when you try to encode objects. For example, you might have a Person object with properties like Name, Age, Height. If you were to write this file as text so that it can be read back in later, you might output something like this:

```
Name:Ralph
Age:25
Height:5'6"
```

But you can represent it more compactly in binary. In binary, you might just output the name, age and height one right after the other, and you'd have to read them back in in the exact same order because you no longer have these delimiters. In that case, your string would have to encoded with something like `Ralph\0`. The `\0` is the null character so that it knows where the string ends.

The `25` can be represented as just 2 characters in text/ASCII but if you tried putting two numbers side-by-side, like 25 and 26, you'd get 2526 and you wouldn't know where one ends and the next begins. These numbers are actually integers and be represented by 4 bytes. When you write a file as binary, you'd write out all 4 bytes, even if the left-most bits are all 0. That way it always knows exactly how much to read it. And so forth...

That's why "binary files" look like jibberish, because they've got all this extra information in them.

To generate these files, you'd have to encode or "pack" your data like John Machin suggests.

Comment: So say for example if I were to go on to write a image file (Not by using some imaging library like PIL), I would be using some sort encoding or packing that is unique to image files? If so, where can I read about such encoding for special files like audio, video or any other file just to grasp the concept.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format BMPs are one of the simpler ones. There's some images that explain it better. For an image, you could encode it by outputting the width, then the height, followed by width*height RGB triplets. Just a bunch of integers, one after the other. Then when you read it back in, you read in 2 integers for the width and height, followed by R,G,B,R,G,B,... this might be considered a "raw" or "unpacked" file format. Jpegs and stuff and crazy complicated because they do a lot of compression on the data, so you'd actually have to uncompress it first before you...

Comment: can even begin to read it. You can read up on the Starcraft 1 map spec too if you want... I did some cool stuff reading and writing those files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your are sending string in your binary file and your computer can decode it and show it to you? Try to write a file with random byte. Or you could show us your code so we can understand the problem.

Comment: How does one write a file with random byte? All I am doing is opening file in brinary mode (open(file,'wb')). I guess I am writing text to it. Do you mean write to a file by using something like pickle module or something?

Comment: @stirred I ges your trying to write like this : file.write("toto") in this case, python will code your text and your computer can read it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the **codecs** module of Python for writing text files (it allows you to set the related charset/encoding). For writing binary file use the standard file() method. On windows you may need use 'wb' or 'rb' for binary modes (does not matter on Unix).